# How to take information from a json file from the internet using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

So, there's this file that I've uploaded in github, and I want my program to take it from there and then save the content written on it in the directory. I've been trying this code:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/Gevez/gameficacao/blob/master/data.json')

with open('data.json','wb') as data:
    data.write(r.content)
```

And the program puts a data.json file in the main directory, but instead of the info that was written in the original file, the json file is filled with the code from the entire githubb page, I will post bellow for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/">

  <link crossorigin="anonymous" media="all" integrity="sha512-veKG2ootplNGLwNEW5It4+lJXwpdOVR1Ry4MBDNvdgL6OgBkiAXaZAZnIKkw6sIygnfGqQhR5q7UdS1llqd6/g==" rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/frameworks-bde286da8a2da653462f03445b922de3.css" />
  <link crossorigin="anonymous" media="all" integrity="sha512-SIdH/u1H0WymCGxSKvv9kCVqCpgpL7GuBc5dVtA1UApgTky3oIA6YLFIzjYiN7fjVk/vZcu/QX5sobbu5BCkmg==" rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/site-488747feed47d16ca6086c522afbfd90.css" />
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" media="all" integrity="sha512-yFRb1O2qllOz/OaFeBzmzWyBBviD8afa5Dc0KKyFZdGvwwzp+I9EFHwjUsNhh2fZp/LWptUugh8+JrE1rtq10A==" rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/github-c8545bd4edaa9653b3fce685781ce6cd.css" />
```

And then it goes on. That's very much not what I was expecting, I really want to download a json.filwith exactly like the one I have uploaded at github.

Please help me.

Comment: Your link is not valid - you get a 404 when trying to access it. Also if you want to retrieve the file directly you should use the `raw` link
i.e  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gevez/gameficacao/master/data-teste-2.json

PS: you should also consider (as a best practice) to use some authentication with requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this url instead?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gevez/gameficacao/master/data-teste-2.json

I think you need the raw output from github.